# Adding new Activity corrupts my gradle file in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have a problem with my Android Studio 2.3.1: When I add a new Activity to my project, my gradle file be corrupted.
Below is my normal `.gradle` file;

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

ext.versionMajor = 0
ext.versionMinor = 0
ext.versionPatch = 1
ext.versionClassifier = ""
ext.minimumSdkVersion = 18

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.android"
        minSdkVersion project.ext.minimumSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode generateVersionCode()
        versionName generateVersionName()

        // enable multi dex support
        //multiDexEnabled true

        // FOR TEST
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    // FOR TEST
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
    //testInstrumentationRunner "com.vancosys.betterkey.MockTestRunner"
}

private Integer generateVersionCode() {
    return ext.minimumSdkVersion * 10000000 + ext.versionMajor * 10000 + ext.versionMinor * 100 + ext.versionPatch
}

private String generateVersionName() {
    String versionName = "${ext.versionMajor}.${ext.versionMinor}.${ext.versionPatch}"
    if (ext.versionClassifier != null && !ext.versionClassifier.isEmpty()) {
        versionName = versionName + "" + ext.versionClassifier
    }
    return versionName;
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    /**
     * FOR UNIT TEST
     */
    // Required -- JUnit 4 framework
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // Optional -- Mockito framework
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'

    /**
     * FOR INSTRUMENTATION TEST
     */
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
    // Optional -- Hamcrest library -- Set this dependency if you want to use the Hamcrest matcher library
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    // Optional -- UI testing with Espresso
    //androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    // If your build configuration includes a compile dependency for the support-annotations library and
    // an androidTestCompile dependency for the espresso-core library,
    // your build might fail due to a dependency conflict.
    // To resolve, update your dependency for espresso-core as follows:
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    // Optional -- UI testing with UI Automator
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'

    // Database, ORM
    compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.4'

    // Field and method binding
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'

    // provides a simple way to add a draggable sliding up panel
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.3.1'

    // awesome bottom sheet
    compile 'com.github.rubensousa:bottomsheetbuilder:1.6.0'

    // awesome search view
    /*compile 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'*/
    compile project(path: ':materialsearchview')
}
```

And below is my `.gradle` file after adding new Activity;

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

ext.versionMajor = 0
ext.versionMinor = 0
ext.versionPatch = 1
ext.versionClassifier = ""
ext.minimumSdkVersion = 18

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.android"
        minSdkVersion project.ext.minimumSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode generateVersionCode()
        versionName generateVersionName()

        // enable multi dex support
        //multiDexEnabled true

        // FOR TEST
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    // FOR TEST
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
    //testInstrumentationRunner "com.vancosys.betterkey.MockTestRunner"
}

private Integer generateVersionCode() {
    return ext.minimumSdkVersion * 10000000 + ext.versionMajor * 10000 + ext.versionMinor * 100 + ext.versionPatch
}

private String generateVersionName() {
    String versionName = "${ext.versionMajor}.${ext.versionMinor}.${ext.versionPatch}"
    if (ext.versionClassifier != null && !ext.versionClassifier.isEmpty()) {
        versionName = versionName + "" + ext.versionClassifier
    }
    return versionName;
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    /**
     * FOR UNIT TEST
     */
    // Required -- JUnit 4 framework
    // Optional -- Mockito framework


    /**
     * FOR INSTRUMENTATION TEST
     */
    // Optional -- Hamcrest library -- Set this dependency if you want to use the Hamcrest matcher library
    // Optional -- UI testing with Espresso
    //androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    // If your build configuration includes a compile dependency for the support-annotations library and
    // an androidTestCompile dependency for the espresso-core library,
    // your build might fail due to a dependency conflict.
    // To resolve, update your dependency for espresso-core as follows:
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    // Optional -- UI testing with UI Automator


    // Database, ORM

    // Field and method binding

    // provides a simple way to add a draggable sliding up panel

    // awesome bottom sheet

    // awesome search view
    /*compile 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'*/
    compile project(path:
    ':materialsearchview')
compile
    'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'compile
    'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'compile
    'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'compile
    'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.4'compile
    'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.rubensousa:bottomsheetbuilder:1.6.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
}
```

As you see, it is corrupted, and give me this error in message panel;

```
Error:(93, 0) Could not get unknown property 'compile' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Does anybody have any idea?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah...Android Studio bug
[image: Here is the difference between the files]
As you see, it messes up dependencies:

```
'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1' compile
```

---- should be ---->

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

Comment: I know this, I resolve the error by fix the gradle file. But why does my gradle file lose its organization every time I add a new Activity?

Comment: it's an Android Studio bug. I also suspect is caused by the comments inside the gradle file. Try removing the comments and see if fixes your problem

Comment: I removed the comments and it fixed. Logically, I understand the bug (Android Studio is reformatting the gradle file content without considering the comments), but basically I don't understand why this happen for me just in this project!

Comment: Yep. I'm not sure also but I knew about the commens since it happened to me in a couple of projects. The gradle file should not even be formatted when creating a new activity since they have no relationship whatsoever. The only thing you can do is hope for a fix in the next versions of Android Studio and you can also update right now to AS 2.3.2 but I'm not sure it's fixed. If I helped fix your problem please consider marking the answer as correct. Thank you!

Comment: 2.3.3, still not fixed